# How to access programs in one PC using another PC

Tags: windows-7, virtualization, vpn, connection

I was recently given an old PC for my remote access at work. The CPU that comes with it has Windows XP installed, 400+ MB of ram, all USB devices disabled. I access my work applications using VPN / Citrix. Basically, it' sooooo slow. Plus it's bulky and it will just occupy space, so I am now hoping to find a way for me to integrate this work PC with my home PC.

I tried to put in the hard drive in my home PC CPU, and set the drive as slave. However, when I booted my PC from this hard drive, I am stuck at the screen where windows is prompting me to select how am I going to boot (ex. Safe Mode, Safe mode with command prompt, Last Working Configuration, etc), but whatever option I select, I am still stuck at this option after reboot.

I am thinking if maybe I can clone the drive and mount the cloned drive and access the system as a virtual machine. But I don't know if that will work.

I would like to know if there's something I can do so I can work at home using my home PC, where I can access my work programs to connect to VPN / Citrix.

My home PC's OS is Windows 7 Ultimate x64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just get a VPN client and install it on your home computer and VPN into your company and do you work that way.

It is a VERY BAD idea to put a hard drive with Windows installed on it into another computer and boot to it. You will damage Windows as it will have to completely reconfigure itself for the new motherboard and other new parts.

Comment: Hi dweebsonduty, I did that, however, the VPN client is not compatible with Windows 7. All settings are hidden so I can't configure them manually if I ever install a VPN client that's windows 7 compatible.

Comment: What VPN software are you using?

Comment: ipsecdialer (Cisco) + Citrix Program Neighborhood